# GDI+ equivalent of GDI Rectangle

Tags: winapi, gdi+, gdi

What is the GDI+ equivalent of the GDI [**Rectangle**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-rectangle) function?

[image]

```
| Library | Outline       | Fill interior | Both        |
|---------|---------------|---------------|-------------|
| GDI     | FrameRect     | FillRect      | Rectangle   |
| GDI+    | DrawRectangle | FillRectangle | ?           |
```

Comment: FillRectangle then DrawRectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## GDI+ version of `Rectangle`

**Delphi**:

```
class procedure TGDIPlusHelper.Rectangle(g: TGPGraphics; OutlinePen: TGPPen; InteriorFillBrush: TGPBrush; x, y, width, height: Single);
begin
    //GDI has Rectangle.
    //GDI+ we simulate it with FillRectangle followed by DrawRectangle
    g.FillRectangle(InteriorFillBrush, x, y, width, height);
    g.DrawRectangle(OutlinePen, x, y, width, height);
end;
```

**C#**:

```
void Rectangle(Graphics g, Pen outlinePen; Brush interiorFillBrush, Single x, Single y, Single width, Single height)
{
    //GDI has Rectangle.
    //GDI+ we simulate it with FillRectangle followed by DrawRectangle
    g.FillRectangle(InteriorFillBrush, x, y, width, height);
    g.DrawRectangle(OutlinePen, x, y, width, height);
}
```